# Refering or Importing Avro Schemas in another Avro Schema

Tags: python, avro

I have a main avro schema and other small avro schemas. The main avro schema refers to the other small avro schemas like below:

Item.avsc

```
{
    "namespace":"com.example.common",
    "name":"Item",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"ItemId",
            "type":"com.example.common.ItemId"
        },
        {
            "name":"features",
            "type":"com.example.common.Features"
        }
    ]
}
```

ItemId.avsc

```
{
    "namespace":"com.example.common",
    "name":"ItemId",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"id",
            "type":"int"
        }
    ]
}
```

Features.avsc

```
{
    "namespace":"com.example.common",
    "name":"Features",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"Range",
            "type":{
                "type":"array",
                "items":"com.example.common.Range"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and there is also a Range.avsc but I didn't wrote it, the question becomes too long.

All these files are in a folder named "com.example.common"

I wrote a simple python line of code to parse and print the schema of Item.avsc:

```
import avro.schema

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("./com.example.common/Item.avsc", "rb").read())
print(schema)
```

But it raises:

```
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Could not make an Avro Schema object from com.example.common.ItemId.
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Type property "com.example.common.ItemId" not a valid Avro schema: Could not make an Avro Schema object from com.example.common.ItemId.
```

How do we read referenced schemas inside a schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done with the standard `avro` library, but if you use the `fastavro` library there is a function that will do it. It is called `load_schema`: https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html#fastavro._schema_py.load_schema

> Will recursively load referenced schemas assuming they can be found in files in the same directory and named with the convention <full_name>.avsc

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```py
from fastavro.schema import load_schema
parsed_schema = load_schema("./com.example.common/Item.avsc")
```